# BarButtonItem & RibbonBarManager Click Event in DevExpress

Tags: winforms, devexpress, ribbon

I have a problem with the DevExpress namely: Button in RibonControl.
I wrote the event "click" for the way the button in RibonControl as follows:

```
 private void barButtonClick_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
 {
    BarButtonItem item = (BarButtonItem)(sender);
    //..... if else ...
 }
```

and I get an error message while running:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonBarManager' to type 'DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem'.
```

I think, this error due to the fact that "click" of the button in DevExpress similar in WPF (routed events), correct? and how to solve?

Comment: Seems like sender is of type `RibbonBarManager`, maybe the `BarButtonItem` is provided in the `ItemClickEventArgs` or maybe you should register the event elsewhere so you'll get a `BarButtonItem`...

Comment: Please post your xaml.

Comment: Have you tried CaptionButtonClick event.

Comment: I really doubt that it is taunt ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the correct code-snippet looks for your task:

```
void barButtonItem_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    BarButtonItem bItem = e.Item as BarButtonItem;
    // ... do something
}
```

Documentation: the [ItemClickEventArgs.Item](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsItemClickEventArgs_Itemtopic) property.

The fact, that `sender` parameter within this event handler is `BarManager` rather than the `BarButtonItem`, can be explained via DevExpress XtraBars Suite architecture.
The main idea is that the `BarItem` is a **non-visual** element that can't be "clicked". The `BarItemLink` element is a **link** to this item that represent item on screen. The `BarManager` instance manage all the interactions with links and route all the events to the corresponding item's and BarManager's event handlers. That's why the `BarManager/RibbonBarManager` instance appears as `sender` parameter within the event handler.

See [Items and Links](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1087) for more details.